# Android: How to send message from a DialogFagment to a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a Fragment, and from that Fragment I show up a DialogFragment, I want the DialogFragment to send message to the Fragment, or rech the Fragment's variables. How can I do tis?

Comment: Hi, I'm curious... why do you use dialog fragment and what will happened if I don't use?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to utilize a Listener pattern for this.  Here's a quick example to get you started:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface MyDialogFragmentListener {
        public void abstract onDialogMessage(int someValueIWantToSendToFragment);
    }

    private MyDialogFragmentListener mListener;


....

    public void setListener(MyDialogFragmentListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


}
```

and then whenever you need to send some bit of data to your fragment from the dialog, call mListener.onDialogMessage(someValue);

Make sure that when you create your dialogfragment, you call setListener on it with an instance of MyDialogFragmentListener.

Answer (score 0):

you can put this code where you want in the dialogFragment:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("message",myMessage);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), MyFragment.class.getName(), args);
ft.replace(R.id.details, fragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

for example in the `onCreate` of dialog fragment we send a message, using bundle:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment { 

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String myMessage="Hello Fragment";
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("message",myMessage);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), MyFragment.class.getName(), args);
        ft.replace(R.id.details, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_about)
                .setTitle(R.string.about)
                .setMessage(R.string.about_message)
                // ...
                .create();
    }
}
```

in `MyFragment` I can get my message, using only this line:

```
getArguments().getString("message");
```